# Excel Copying data to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Trying to do a worksheet for a Till Check, all data is entered manually, with that data then being copied to another sheet for future reference, now I have accomplished this bit (havn't coded in excel in yonks) However a little problem is it's copying that data multiple times, so instead of just 1 entry per row there's 5 rows with entered data.

A single row should have 5 different entries, Date, Cash Sales, Eftpos Sales, Totals, Checked By.

```
Sub Button2_Click()

  Dim rng As Range
  Dim i As Long
  Dim a As Long
  Dim rng_dest As Range
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  i = 1

  Set rng_dest = Sheets("Till Reports").Range("A:D")


  ' Find first empty row in columns D:G on sheet Invoice data

  Do Until WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng_dest.Rows(i)) = 0

    i = i + 1

  Loop


  Set rng = Sheets("Till Checks").Range("E21:F26")


  ' Copy rows containing values to sheet Till Checks


  For a = 1 To rng.Rows.Count


    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng.Rows(a)) <> 0 Then


      rng_dest.Rows(i).Value = rng.Rows(a).Value

      Sheets("Till Reports").Range("D" & i).Value = Sheets("Till Checks").Range("F24").Value
      Sheets("Till Reports").Range("A" & i).Value = Sheets("Till Checks").Range("E21").Value
      Sheets("Till Reports").Range("B" & i).Value = Sheets("Till Checks").Range("F22").Value
      Sheets("Till Reports").Range("C" & i).Value = Sheets("Till Checks").Range("F23").Value
      Sheets("Till Reports").Range("E" & i).Value = Sheets("Till Checks").Range("F25").Value

      i = i + 1

    End If
```

Comment: Can you post some of your main worksheet and summary sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is your `For a = 1 To rng.Rows.Count`. Remove that and it should do it once.

Comment: Thanks mate, works fine now - Been looking at it for ages trying to figure out what was doing it - I reworked the script from a previous one, next time I think I'll just rewrite it again.